# Xamarin app deploy - Are all dependencies included in app package (apk)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, dependency-injection, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin and don't know how solution deployment actually works.
Lets assume I have dependencies in my project as shown in the diagram below:
[image]
**Does this mean that deploying the app will cause all projects to be included?** For this particular case, `Mobile` app doesn't use the `CoreServices`, which calls `RestService` and `Data`, but it is also calling the same `CoreServices` that `Web` uses.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker

Answer (score 3):

Your app will include everything that is required by any referenced assembly or project. For example: If BP.Mobile references CoreServices which references RestServices all these project build results will be included in your app that references BP.Mobile. Plus all the assemblies coming with NuGet-packages.

What is inside your app can be easily seen if you analyze your apk with Android Studio. Or rename your apk to zip and un-package it.

Comment: Your statement about everything referenced being included is true when the package is built with no linking. Otherwise, *"Linking is based on static analysis. Consequently, anything that depends upon the runtime environment won't be detected"*. Linking results in a significantly smaller package (18% of original size), but requires the Mono runtime to be deployed onto the target device.

Answer (score -1):

> **Linking on Android**
>
> Xamarin.Android applications use a linker to reduce the size of the
> application. The linker employes static analysis of your application
> to determine which assemblies are actually used, which types are
> actually used, and which members are actually used. The linker then
> behaves like a garbage collector, continually looking for the
> assemblies, types, and members that are referenced until the entire
> closure of referenced assemblies, types, and members is found. Then
> everything outside of this closure is discarded.
>
> **Linker Behavior**
>
> The primary mechanism for controlling the linker is the Linker
> Behavior (Linking in Visual Studio) drop-down within the Project
> Options dialog box. There are three options:
>
> 1. Don't Link (None in Visual Studio)
> 2. Link SDK Assemblies (Sdk Assemblies Only)
> 3. Link All Assemblies (Sdk and User Assemblies)

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker

[image]

[image]

**Note:** The *Advanced* button (bottom right) brings up a dialog for setting the target architecture (ARM, x86, x64, etc...) along with some other options that probably shouldn't be messed with typically.